# AWS EC2 - Developer dynamic ip permission

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

Every single day I need to update inbound rules, because the dev team is at homeoffice.

Is there any solution for my dev team with dynamic IP addresses?

Answer (score 2):

Since your team's IP addresess change and you only want to allow those specific IP addresses, you are out of luck: you need to update Security Groups inbound rules every time the IP changes.

What you can do though is *simplify* this process. AWS recently announced [Prefix Lists](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/06/amazon-virtual-private-cloud-customers-use-prefix-lists-simplify-configuration-security-groups-route-tables/). You can create a Prefix List with all your team's IP addresses and reference this in any Security Group you need. You can then maintain *one* Prefix List instead of a number of Security Groups.

If you are willing to increase your exposure to a wider IP range, as a trade-off for less frequent IP address list maintenance, you can add your user's CIDR block instead of each specific IP address. Then, assuming that most dynamic IP addresses are allocated from the same CIDR block, your team members will be able to connect to your EC2 instances. A simple `whois` query for a specific IP address can show you the CIDR (IP range) it belongs too (usually your ISP's CIDR).